# How to Listen custom Keyboard Key Events in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have created a custom Keyboard in android but how to Listen for Key Events without EditText .the keyboard is visible

```
 CustomKeyboard customKeyboard;
 customKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this,R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
```

Or is there any methods to read from softkeyboard